# Dependent and independent random variables, transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The following is a PDF of two independent random variables $x_1$, $x_2$
$$
f(x_1, x_2) = f_1 (x_1) f_2 (x_2)
$$

We can make a transformation of variables
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= h_1 (x_1, x_2) \\
y_2 &= h_2 (x_1, x_2)
\end{aligned}
$$

The PDF of two random variables $y_1$, $y_2$ is
$$
g(y_1, y_2) = \iint \mathrm{d} x_1 \, \mathrm{d} x_2 \, f (x_1, x_2) \, \delta (y_1 - h_1 (x_1, x_2)) \, \delta (y_2 - h_2 (x_1, x_2))
$$

In general, $g (y_1, y_2)$ is *not* in the form of $g_1 (y_1) g_2 (y_2)$, i.e. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not independent.

Questions:

1. given independent variables $x_1, x_2$, what is the most general form of functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are still independent? My suspicion is that $h_1$ and $h_2$ must only depend on one variable, i.e. any mixing of $x_1$ and $x_2$ will result in dependency. Proving $y_1 = h_1 (x_1)$, $y_2 = h_2 (x_2)$ necessarily leads to $y_1, y_2$ being independent is easy from the formula above, however, I'm not sure how I'd prove that any sort of mixing of $x_1, x_2$ leads to $y_1, y_2$ being dependent
2. Inverse problem: given two *dependent* random variables $y_1$, $y_2$ with a known joint PDF $g (y_1, y_2)$, is there a transformation $x_1 = h_1 (y_1, y_2)$, $x_2 = h_2 (y_1, y_2)$ such that $x_1, x_2$ are now *independent* random variables (existence question)? Can we find such transformation explicitly by some construction (could be iterative, approximate, ...)? How about higher dimensions, 3, 4, etc. random variables?

Comment: I do not believe your suspicion is always correct.  Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and try $y_1=x_1+x_2$ and $y_2=x_1-x_2$ which I think are independent $\mathcal N(0,2)$

Comment: @Henry you're right, it seems to me they are independent! Okay, what is then the set of transformations $\vec{x} \to \vec{y}$ such that the variables stay independent? I think this depends on the original distribution...

The question 2. is much important to me.